# C# Dynamic Linq: Strings are assumed to be integers?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I'm using the System.Linq.Dynamic library found here, which is simply an upload of Microsoft's library to be accessible via NuGet: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

In my code, I have this function that gets a list of objects from a database that match a certain property. It needed to be as flexible as possible, so the parameters consist of three strings;

- One for the "order by" statement
- One for the property to match's name
- One for the expected property's value

Here's the line of code that's giving me trouble:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetByProperty(string propertyName, string propertyValue,
    string orderStatement)
{
    return _context.Set<T>()
        .OrderBy(orderStatement)
        .Where(propertyName + " = " + propertyValue);
}
```

Here are the possible scenarios;

- propertyValue contains only numbers: the query works perfectly.
- propertyValue starts with numbers but has letters in it: the following error appears: `Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'`
- propertyValue is anything else: the following error appears: `No property or field '[the first part of the "propertyValue string, up until it meets an empty space, a "-" or some other specific characters]' exists in type '[Class name of <T>]'`

I've tried using single quotes to surround my string, but I then get the error: `'Character literal must contain exactly one character'`

I've also desperately tried to add ".ToString()" at the end to try and trick something into working, but I found the error: `Digit expected`.

Is there another way to use the "Where" clause, in Linq and Dynamic Linq, that would support the flexibility I'm trying to have using this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the type of the property and format the value accordingly. If it is a string, enclose it in double quotes. i.e. `name =  "John"` but `age = 20`.

It does not depend whether the value looks like a number or not.

- If the type of the property is a **number** type then the value must be a number as well and not be enclosed in quotes.
- If the type of the property is a **string** then the value must be enclosed in double quotes, even if the value is a number (e.g. `code = "3"`).

Comment: I was convinced it wasn't right, but it turns out my code crashed when I referred to an int as a string, and the opposite made it crash too. I've implemented your solution by creating methods for every variable type I could be expecting in the SQL calls and everything runs smoothly! Many thanks!